# How to combine two lines into one line using closing brackets in a case environment with 3 lines?

Tags: brackets, mathtools, cases

For example, in LaTeX, I have three conditions in one "cases" environment. Then I could get a  new condition from the combination of the first and the second conditions, so I want to use a right curly bracket to combine them, just like the following:

[image]

However, I don't know how to insert such a bracket to cover these two "lambda" equations.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

```tex
\[
\begin{cases}
    2 = 2 \lambda x \\
    3 = 2 \lambda y \\
    x^2 + y^2 - 4 = 0
\end{cases}
\quad \Rightarrow \quad
\begin{cases}
    \lambda = \frac{1}{x}\\
    \lambda = \frac{3}{2y}\\
    x^2 + y^2 - 4 = 0
\end{cases}
\]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. Here's one - using an `array` to insert a null delimiter on the left and `\}` on the right.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{cases}
    2 = 2 \lambda x \\
    3 = 2 \lambda y \\
    x^2 + y^2 - 4 = 0
  \end{cases}
  \quad \Rightarrow \quad
  \begin{cases}
    \kern-\nulldelimiterspace
    \left.\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
      \lambda = \frac{1}{x} \\[\jot]
      \lambda = \frac{3}{2y}
    \end{array}\right\} \\
    x^2 + y^2 - 4 = 0
  \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package, which is superset of the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package (and, in fact, automatically loads the `amsmath` package) provides environments called `dcases` and `drcases`, which render their contents in display math mode by default; using display math mode is indicated when having to typeset systems of equations. The letter `r` in `drcases` indicates that the tall curly brace will be placed to the *right* of the environment.

As is done in [@Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/681476/5001), I also suggest executing `\kern-\nulldelimiterspace` immediately before `\begin{drcases}`, in order offset the amount of horizontal whitespace that's inserted right before that environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'dcases' and 'drcases' environments
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{dcases}
    2 = 2\lambda x \\
    3 = 2\lambda y \\
    x^2+y^2-4=0
\end{dcases}
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
\begin{dcases}
    \kern-\nulldelimiterspace
    \begin{drcases}
        \lambda = 1/x  \\
        \lambda = 3/(2y) 
    \end{drcases} \\
    x^2+y^2-4=0
\end{dcases}
\]

\end{document}
```